# Gradle native app automatically add unwanted options

Tags: c++, gradle

I'm evaluating Gradle to include in my C++ workflow, installation worked fine but when I'm trying to create a 'cpp-application', Gradle automatically adds -nostdinc in the compiler options.

I can't seem to find people who already had this problem, does anybody has a solution ?

UPDATE: I just realized that additionnal informations are needed !
I am using CentOS 6.9 and Gradle 5.4.1

Gradle doesn't add path to C++ headers after the -nostdinc.

Comment: Does it not add in the system include paths afterwards or...? Searching for "gradle nostdinc" [brings up](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-native/issues/551) [some issues](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-native/issues/564)

Comment: @Botje No nothing added after ! The issues you linked are from an older version, and don't seem to have been "answered", so I was hoping someone had a solution to prevent gradle from adding this option !

Comment: I tried to reproduce your scenario using CentOS 7 and Clang. The `build/tmp/CompileDebugCpp/options.txt` *does* contain `-nostdinc`, but then a lot of `-I` and `-isystem` lines to include exactly what is needed. Is it possible you are missing the `gcc-c++` or `glibc-devel` packages?

Comment: I have those packages installed but no system include is made in any way !
Thanks for the time you spent trying to help me, I think I might go on Gradle forums instead to see if anybody from Gradle can find a solution !

Comment: Try running `gradle --info assemble`. The "configure project" step lists the commands it executes to determine what system headers it should include. For me it runs `/usr/bin/g++ -m64 -x c++ -dM -E -v - < /dev/null` among others.

Comment: It runs the same commands but without the input of /dev/null.
Maybe this a problem ?

Comment: Well, it does not print the `< /dev/null` bit, I added that. Does the command produce a usable set of include directories?